# Dynamic SQL accept table column as input in a procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, runtime-error, dynamic-sql, procedure

Hey I am trying to write a procedure in which the user can `insert` which columns he would like to get as `parameter input`.  As of right now when I run a test `script` I get this error:

```
error -1 message error in ct_cu_act_medrecon_pg.spm_search_patientmedrecs =>ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

The error is refering to the `order by` part in the `select statement`, and when I remove that I get an error saying:

```
error -1 message error in ct_cu_act_medrecon_pg.spm_search_patientmedrecs =>ORA-00904: "D"."P_INSERTDT_IN": invalid identifier
```

Here is the spec:

```
procedure spm_search_patientmedrecs (
  p_columnsort_in  in varchar2, --which is sort column
  p_medmed_in      in varchar2, --first column
  p_planid_in      in varchar2, --second column
  p_detmed_in      in varchar2, --third column
  p_insertdt_in    in varchar2, --fourth column
  p_ascdesc_in     in varchar2, --asc or desc in order by
  p_return_cur_out out sys_refcursor,
  p_err_code_out   out number,
  p_err_mesg_out   out varchar2
);
```

Here is the procedure body:

```
procedure spm_search_patientmedrecs (
  p_columnsort_in  in varchar2,
  p_medmed_in      in varchar2,
  p_planid_in      in varchar2,
  p_detmed_in      in varchar2,
  p_insertdt_in    in varchar2,
  p_ascdesc_in     in varchar2,
  p_return_cur_out out sys_refcursor,
  p_err_code_out   out number,
  p_err_mesg_out   out varchar2)
is
  lv_sql           varchar2(32767);
begin
  lv_sql := '';
  lv_sql := 'select h.p_medmed_in,
                    h.p_planid_in,
                    d.p_detmed_in,
                    d.p_insertdt_in
             from membermedicalreconcilationhdr h,
                  membermedicalreconcilationdet d
             where h.membermedreconciliationhdrskey = 
                   d.membermedreconciliationhdrskey
             order by h.p_columnsort_in p_ascdesc_in';
    p_err_code_out := 0;
    OPEN p_return_cur_out FOR lv_sql;
exception
  when others then
    p_err_code_out := -1;
    p_err_mesg_out := 'error in ct_cu_act_medrecon_pg.spm_search_patientmedrecs =>'||sqlerrm;
end spm_search_patientmedrecs;
```

Here is my test script:

```
set serveroutput on
declare 
  type tempcursor is ref cursor;
  v_cur_result tempcursor;
  errcode number;
  errmesg varchar2(1000);
begin
  ct_cu_act_medrecon_pg.spm_search_patientmedrecs
    ('primarymemberplanid',
     'membermedreconciliationhdrskey',
     'primarymemberplanid',
     'membermedreconciliationdetskey',
     'inserteddt',
     'ASC',
     v_cur_result,
     errcode,
     errmesg
     );

--  dbms_output.put_line(v_cur_result);
  dbms_output.put_line('error '||errcode||' message '||errmesg);
end;
```

First off, I know how I'm handeling the error isnt the best way to do it but thats how the person asking me to do this wanted it.

Now I dont know if this is a possible thing to do in `Oracle PL/SQL`, but if it is I would greatly appreciate some help in pointing me in the right direction.  If you guys need any more information feel free to ask and I will assist as best I can (Ive only been working with SQL and PL/SQL for 2 months).  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamic SQL means assembling strings which are executed as SQL statements.  Your string hardcodes the parameter names, whereas what you actually need is the contents of the  parameters.

Something like this:

```
lv_sql := 'select h.'||p_medmed_in||',
                    h.'||p_planid_in||',
                    d.'||p_detmed_in||',
                    d.'||p_insertdt_in||'
             from membermedicalreconcilationhdr h,
                  membermedicalreconcilationdet d
             where h.membermedreconciliationhdrskey = 
                   d.membermedreconciliationhdrskey
             order by h.'||p_columnsort_in||' '|| p_ascdesc_in;
```

Comment: Ahhhh interesting, let me check this out and see how it goes.  Thank you for your timely response and for clearing up dynamic sql for me.

Comment: @Alex - well I did say "something like this" :)  Thanks for tidying up after me!